# Difference between "term" and "period"

Tags: time

What is the difference  between *term* and *period* in meaning *distance in time*?

Is it possible to use one or both of them when we describe a point in time (*We have time till 1st of December so we have to finish the project within this term/period*) and when we describe duration (*We have two weeks so we have to finish...*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, a *term* is more rigid and finite than a *period*.

**[term](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/term)**:

> 2a : a limited or definite extent of time; especially : the time for which something lasts : duration, tenure [term of office] [lost money in the short term]

Examples:  academic term, term paper, term life insurance, to carry a baby to term

[**period**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/period):

> a : a portion of time determined by some recurring phenomenon

### Edit to address OP's question edits:

> Is it possible to use one or both of them when we describe a point in
>   time (We have time till 1st of December so we have to finish the
>   project within this term/period)

You could say *we have a December 1st deadline, so we have to finish the project within this period* (between now and December 1st).  What you will often see instead of *period* here is *[**time frame**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timeframe)*:

> : a period of time especially with respect to some action or project

The second part of your question:

> and when we describe duration (We have two weeks so we have to finish...)?

*...within this period* or *...within this time frame* are a better fit than *term*.